# Unable to load a website in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html

I want to register for a course using the Sign-Up option and I want to load a website in an iFrame. The website specifies the `X-Frame-Options = ALLOW`

But when I click on the Sign-Up button, the website is redirected to its homepage and I am not able to load it in my iFrame.

Why am I not able to load the URL in my iFrame?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Screenshots? It's sort of hard to tell what's going on without actually seeing what your doing.

Comment: Could be one of a billion reasons. Impossible for us to answer. Most likely it is code in the website redirecting and you will not be able to do anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

It 's not you not being able to load the site in the iframe. The site is loading in the iframe but the sign in action is set to the `top` `window`  as `target`, so when you submit the credentials it force the response to be loaded in the most top window.

Comment: I was able to load MIT's website into my iFrame (http://www.mit.edu). But I tried to load the following website in iFrame and it is redirecting to its homepage (https://www.iitbombayx.in/register).

Comment: From one site to another, depending on their particular scripts, you may or you may not use them in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you create a **form**  with name **theForm** and want send the form to display the result in an iFrame container.

`<iframe name='iframe_name' width='200' height='200'></iframe>`

```
<form id="theForm" action="example.php" method="GET" target="iframe_name">
   <input name="username" type="text" value="">
   <input name="password" type="text" value="">
   <input name="sender" type="text" value="">
  <script>
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
  </script>
</form>
```